# I'm unable to send email through django

Tags: django

I have a Django project hosted on a shared hosting server, While I'm trying to send an email it's not working.

Below is my code,

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'ninjawebhub.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@ninjawebhub.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '------'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False

def contact(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        data = Contact(
            first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
            last_name = request.POST['last_name'],
            email = request.POST['email'],
            phone = request.POST['phone'],
            message = request.POST['message']      

        )
        data.save()  

        send_mail(
                'Contact Form',
                'Here is the message.',
                'info@ninjawebhub.com',
                ['info@ninjawebhub.com'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )

    return render(request, 'contact.html',{'title': 'Contact Us'})
```

Comment: where have you defined the EMAIL_BACKEND?  you should declare it in sertings.py

Comment: Yes i have declare it in setting.py

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct EMAIL_HOST for smtp protocol on your server? Code looks good.

Comment: @AbdulBasit Which service are you using for emailing?

Comment: I'm using Namecheap shared hosting email service. I tried google smtp but gives me error of "Error: 101 Network is unreachable while using send_mail"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following settings

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

And make sure your email host setting is proper.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' (<-- Sample For GMAIL )
```